# How to implement sliding views for a user interface in a music player

Tags: android

I want to implement this particular design pattern for a music player. How do I start? Any resources or tutorials are also welcome.

**(1) Here I have a list of songs in a list view**

[image]

**(2) I click a song and a panel slides upwards from the bottom**

[image]

**(3) The panel fills the screen with album art and play controls**

[image]

**(4) I can slide the panels into new songs panels**

[image]

**(6) I click back and the panels slides down**

[image]

**(7) The panel remains at the bottom of the screen as a play controle**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take three Relative Layouts Inside your Top Sliding Panel Activity or Layout
And Add `onSwipleListener` to Relative Layouts,make them as a Loop.

or

You can Simply Use ViewPager into your Second Activity to Achieve That.

> http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html